# Media Storage app taking too much space

Tags: internal-storage, insufficient-memory, media-files, vivo

I have been using Vivo Iqoo Z6 Pro with 8GB base RAM and 128GB storage for about a week now. This app called Media Storage used to take up almost no space on my phone. And just four days ago, I noticed that the app had taken about 5GB of space. I wasn't so sure then, so I waited a bit more. And today, the same system app has taken up more than 10GB of my space. I don't know what to do. I can't even reset it.

> [image] . [image]

I connected my phone to my laptop and cleared the media module folder through ADB (`adb shell pm clear com.google.android.providers.media.module`), but still, the app shows no signs of taking less storage.

How do I clear the app data? Please help. Btw my media files and photos take up different storage, they have nothing to do with this.

Comment: Please include exactly the command(s) you have performed via adb.

Comment: adb shell pm clear com.google.android.providers.media.module